# bind same control with array and track changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, knockout.js

I have a page in my asp.net application (non MVC) in which I have some controls - dropdowns and textbox (non server side) and an array of json with certain properties set. Each element can have different set of properties but controls are rendered on the basis of those properties and if user makes any changes, the json entity should also be modified accordingly.

Challenge here is to use same set of controls but bind different entity every time user clicks on the entity.

Question - How is it possible in Knockout js?

If not knockout js, what is the best solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you provide your attempt on a Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Knockout would probably be well suited to deal with this. An `observableArray` can pack a set of objects, each representing the model for a set of controls, and then that model can contain an `observable` for each value. Both the array and the individual values of the models can be polled for changes.

Without knowing more precisely what it is you are looking for, I made this [basic fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leopld/R2sRf/) that illustrates how it could all be rendered to the HTML. The [knockout docs has more on working JSON](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html), but it would be simple to save it to a JSON object any time an observable changing by using the `subscribe` method on an observable.

Then there's also the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for conveniently mapping a JSON object from the backend to a set of observables in knockout.

Hope that answers your question!